# Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'bool') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I am trying to pass to react-native a BOOL from objective C. My code is:

```
-(void)editProfile:(BOOL) success
{
  [self sendEventWithName:@"editUserProfile" body:success];
}
```

I keep getting the error:

Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'bool') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The `body` parameter is an object, not a primitive. You need to convert `success` to an NSNumber. The easiest way is with `@()`:

```
[self sendEventWithName:@"editUserProfile" body:@(success)];
```